# why is 'location cannot be determined' coming up on devices?

Tags: android, kotlin

Code works fine within android studio. Physical devices (multiple, with permission pop up accepted, shows accepted in settings) it doesn't .

When I run it as an internal test on my device (via Google play store), the map activity loads, but it's blank and when I do an on click method within that activity, it states that my location cannot be determined.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Am i missing something obvious here?

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    locationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    locationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location) {
            updateMap(p0)
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(s: String, i: Int, bundle: Bundle) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(s: String) {}
        override fun onProviderDisabled(s: String) {}
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            1
        )
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            5000,
            100f,
            locationListener
        )
        if (locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
            val lastKnownLocation =
                locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            updateMap(lastKnownLocation!!)
        }
    }
```

Any help for a noob (hobbyist) would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance - Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to enable you map to showing your current location, you have to set my location enable to true after checking the user permission is granted.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ){
// permission here is granted
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: You're a diamond. Let me try it now.

Comment: ok, so i can see myself on the map (amazing thanks :D) , yet when i click the onclick button, it still states cannot determine location? weird right?

Comment: Still not sure what is exactly going on. It's showing my position on the screen, but the LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER is returing null when used on a device

Comment: hi buddy, do you request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY to enable GPS?

Comment: be sure you request the user to enable GPS before trying to get the location updates as you use the GPS as the location provider.

Comment: I'll try it now Ramy, thanks. Edit: I'm using the Android API not the Google Play API so not sure that advice helps me